# Pulling Azure work items with Ktor 2.3.3 - Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, azure-devops, ktor

-Update- The HttpStatus is 401 Unauthorized. suggest that the header is wrong.
I am new to pulling items from a REST API and to Ktor. I am trying to pull Azure DevOps work items.

I have this object and when I run the generated URL in the browser I get all the information that I expect, but if I evaluate the call I get an empty string. This makes me think it is either an authorization problem or I am unsure if I structured the call correctly. Does anyone have suggestions on where the error lies?

```
import io.ktor.client.*
import io.ktor.client.call.*
import io.ktor.client.plugins.contentnegotiation.*
import io.ktor.client.request.*
import io.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json.*
import java.util.*

object AzureDevOpsClient {
    private const val BASE_URL = "mydevops.com"
    private const val API_VERSION = "6.0"

    private val client = HttpClient() {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
           json()
        }
    }

    suspend fun getWorkItems(patToken: String, ids: List<Int>): String {
        val url = "$BASE_URL?ids=${ids.joinToString(",")}&api-version=$API_VERSION"
        val headers = mapOf(
            "Authorization" to "Basic ${Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(":".toByteArray())}${Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(patToken.toByteArray())}"
        )

        return client.get {
            url(url)
            headers.forEach { (key, value) ->
                header(key, value)
            }
        }.body<String>()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please check the status code returned from the server? (`HttpResponse.status`)?

Comment: 401 Unauthorized, well that definitely helps.

Answer (score 0):

By using implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-auth:2.3.3") I was allowed to install credentials which got me past the 401.

```
  install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json()
        }
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.DEFAULT
            level = LogLevel.ALL
        }
        install(Auth) {
            basic {
                credentials {
                    BasicAuthCredentials(username = "CollectionName", password = "PAT")
                }
            }
        }
```